# PCA for sentiment analysis tweets

Tags: pca, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a research project that will relate the sentiment analysis done on tweets with financial markets indexes, such as S&P500 and VIX. My work is based on the [Tetlock (2007)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2007.01232.x) paper.

So I have categorized every word in every tweet according to Harvard IV psychological dictionary and then summarise it on a daily basis (i.e. got the frequency of each category per day). Then, rescaled my frequencies dividing by total number of words of all tweets on that day. Also, I have selected only a few categories and not all 180+.

The idea is to construct a factor that captures the latent sentiment on those tweets and the obvious choice is to run a PCA on my frequency sentiment categories data (it is also Tetlock's approach).

My issue is that categories such as Pstv and Ngtv have the same loading signs for the first factor, while I expected them to have opposite signs. [Here is a print screen of the R console where we see the loadings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg3Pi.png) and [here the screeplot of the components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDESN.png).

Any ideia why this would happen?